# stop sending response to angular http and loading new jsp page from controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, model-view-controller

i want to make a angular http call in a jsp page to spring mvc controller (by submiting json data)and i dont want to get response to angular http call instead of that i want to load a new jsp page from the spting mvc controller with executed controller method.

can any one share controller method how to write(for loading new page not sending response back to angular http call)and angular http call if having any different process.[image: angular http call]

[image: spring mvc controller method]

Comment: Please post code as code not as images.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect to a new jsp page new return a new ModelAndView like this

`ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm");
modelAndView.addObject("modelAttribute" , new ModelAttribute());
return modelAndView;`

add your data in the model attribute and access the model attribute in the jsp page using the ${} syntax.

Comment: angular http code showing error in browser console that spring mvc controller not sending response as Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The view you are redirecting to.....make sure it can be resolved by spring view resolver